# How to keep toolbar in place under navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I have a UITableViewController embedded in a navigation controller.  I put a toolbar under the navigation bar to extend it.  It looks like this:

[image]

However, when I swipe up to see more table view cells, the toolbar slides behind the navigation bar and disappears.  Is there a way to attach it permanently under the navigation bar without it moving when I move the table cells?

Comment: How did you put the toolbar under the navigation bar?  Is it part of the table?

Comment: Ya i squeezed it in the tableView

Comment: Like it's a header or row?

Comment: right beneath the navigation bar and just above the "prototype cells"

Answer (score 0):

If you add a subview to a `UITableViewController` it will scroll with it's content.  `UITableViewController` is a specific type of `ViewController` that displays a fullscreen table.

To add another subview as a fixed header,  you can create a custom `UIViewController` that has a `UITableView` as a subview. You then implement the protocols `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` to gain the functionality of a `UITableViewController`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.delegate = self;
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // change to data
        return 5;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // can also use custom cell from xib
        var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("default");

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "default");
        }

        cell!.textLabel!.text = "example";

        return cell!;
    }

}
```

[image: storyboard example]

It's also worth noting that if you are planning on using this toolbar across multiple `UIViewController`s in your storyboard you should use a Container View to specify and re-use it's design.

Answer (score 0):

Set your table style to **UITableViewStyleGrouped** and add your toolbar as the section header using:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _yourtoolbar;
}
```

Comment: This question is tagged "swift". Your solution may have value, but is not written in the language requested by OP - please provide an answer in Swift. Thank you.